Micronaut EclipseStore data is lost after application restart
I want to use Micronaut Eclipsestore as storage in my application, but I found the data would be lost after restarting my application.
what I did

added a DependencyDTO in the storage and it was successful
looked list() function up and it returned the value
restarted the application, called list() function once more and it returned empty.

my applicaton.yml configuration
eclipsestore:
  storage:
    versions:
      root-class: my.package.name/domain/DependencyContainer
      storage-directory: dependency-storage
      channel-count: 1

my functions for adding data to the storage
private final RootProvider<DependencyContainer> rootProvider;

public DependencyRepositoryImpl(RootProvider<DependencyContainer> rootProvider) {
    this.rootProvider = rootProvider;
}

@Override
public Collection<Dependency> list(){return rootProvider.root().getDependencyMap().values();}

@Override
public Dependency create(DependencyDTO dependencyDTO) throws DependencyDuplicateException {
    Map<String, Dependency> dependencyMap = rootProvider.root().getDependencyMap();
    return performCreate(dependencyMap, dependencyDTO);
}

@StoreParams("versions")
protected Dependency performCreate(Map<String, Dependency> dependencyMap, DependencyDTO dependencyDTO) {
    Dependency newDependency = new Dependency(dependencyDTO.getDependencyName(),
            dependencyDTO.getGithubPath()
    );
    dependencyMap.put(dependencyDTO.getDependencyName(), newDependency);
    return newDependency;
}


The Map name should be the same in root class and in @StoreParams, here is dependencyMap.
in root class
private final Map<String, Dependency> dependencyMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

in repository implementation
@StoreParams("dependencyMap")
protected Dependency performCreate() {}

